# Рассылка по id в телеграме с помощью юзербота останавливается

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

Написал на библиотеке Telethon скрипт для юзербота,чтобы он делал массовую рассылку.Я захожу в группу,пишу ответом команду для отправки и оно отправляется в лс каждому в группе.Проблема в том,что скрипт останавливается тогда,когда доходит до седьмого человека.В чем может быть проблема?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient,  sync, events 

    import asyncio
    import telethon
    import sys
    import json
    import time
    from telethon import functions, types
    from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ExportChatInviteRequest
    
    with open("config.json") as json_data_file:
        config = json.load(json_data_file)
    
    api_id = config["api_id"]
    api_hash = config["api_hash"]
    session = config["sessionname"]
    
    client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
    print("Bot started")
    print("Api_ID: " + str(api_id))
    print("Api_Hash: " + api_hash)
    
    
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'(?i).*\b(sendall)\b'))
    async def handler(event):
          c = await client.get_participants(event.to_id, limit=10000)
          reply = await event.get_reply_message()
          print("Message: %s" % str(reply.message))  
          x = 0
          while x < 10000:
                    time.sleep(0.800)
                    members = c[x].id  
                    # 
                    await client.send_message("me", str(reply.message)) 
                # 
                    print("Send to ID: %s" % members)
                    x += 1
    
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет в консоли?

Comment: Нет,просит авторизацию по номеру,я ввожу его,получаю пароль,запускаю рассылку и в логе пишется: sent to id (тут номер ид) семь раз и дальше не идет

Comment: Кст, щас обратил внимание, что у вас используется `time.sleep` в асинхронной функции, в них ведь другой sleep используется -- специальный. Я бы еще порекомендовал в `handler` все обернуть в try/except, и ловить все исключения от Exception, возможно была ошибка в `handler`, которую `telethon` поймал и "съел"

Comment: Спасибо,буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

```
api_id = config["api_id"]
api_hash = config["api_hash"]
```

в этих строках должны быть 1. Api 2. Api-hash

Comment: Они импортируются из config.json

Comment: Если бы проблема была с api_id и api_hash, то бот вообще бы не заработал